# Type operations behave differently when inside a generic function. Trying to figure out why

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type with optional fields. Through a type utility I make one of them required, and I can index into the deeper object through this now required key just fine.

But when I do the exact same operations inside a generic function, TypeScript acts like that field is not made required, and does not allow me to index into it. I check the derived type from the function to check its signature and everything looks as expected. But still TS does not allow me to index into the object.

[Well annotated reproduction playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCuBcEsBsGcC4BQ4CeAHApgAgLIEMBrDAaQxQCUMBHUSAJwwBMAeAeQCMArLDAD3AwA7RrCwB7LhgDG4ADRZiPfkJFYiKMQDMsHTgD4sAXh0BbSODZd5xAwDIsAb0RYsAbXVZIghQF0AtAD88DpcrsQ+ANyIAL6IiCDgYkpoeMJYqYxYjBjsoADmWKiYogAW4OBoCCB55iWg7AB0UmImwGZSdGKwWuDAACroGADKHZBovZCwsKAYsMAATAAcAKwADIsAxJPT0i0mQuB+AOxHywCcqwAsl+fIg1gAkix9BsZ9SgLCohKc0uBYAUc0Sw9gcbgACp5vOotFg+j5gk9mH1XOCfAZgcE+hEsHEQH4CYSicSSYT4sBuqA6FJsD8-oVBndMFhwV1YJB2NASGRRMYAERiQQYPlYAA+WD54AA7mI+VEitgAHKzASMXRGRxuMTjSCCvDQUgoKEstkcrmG2A+IKa7IYNDBQSgEzsDB0LDRaJRJnYIbUgDqtUoNHoTFYQo1+CIhqDtAYLGVsFVunkAqFfL0eOAguwkywDGDcfkgiSrs6brwoj4mBkTCwLugYil3qwAHFQHg6KkBKHw8ZfVIA+ASjGQ2qha5U8KfBPbWg+ZFM1JUgByf5ebK8OtG2d16R4UCwbCSmUipfeF1YUDCDCaLxMclD7A1ABuQh4dDLnlExboJn16TSKs-iYWRm1YHU9WgPoZQ1ftB2HahYx7DAJ2lWVpz5Wd5y9EB9WgcRtEfdJ2DEV8v2SYDMgyLA8jEMRGEzXJ-grdIaKEV1ICkdI6DyJ0DmNPAsE0K8ZF1QR5CHLw8lEF0SjwMjGEgTRNFdA5oBQJBhMEUTBTYoU6E4gAxESoEFZgHkENAIA+FRRATJMuD0AAKABKRxnBcBlmTgwNENHMNsGMSNuQoPy43MyyIBTbN0wiEBYDwfZCgYPBwH2QRmNEPASNfDyXDyrAEhKbBSzEN160bcjFVYd4AFEAA1wVqgBhPpaoAEQaR4sFgEoxFAaBMgvbKuUKJJ1z4LcJSwrBOAPf5oEgIhCmK4jSIwAICoVVt207DKMGQ2D-V8gtkInGKMKwhcCqKp9IFfbxSrdXMgJrTJFuW8xyP68B2WyFbsC0nTBC2+5wNMwR9WgpI+2OocRzjALUJPS6Drna7PMK-okikYqpAILApTk-4FVgUZxnSGR22gdSsg419RE0MqsB8+GwrOydsNxTGQAePMMHAKlvCI7bNE6EwAaEkyxKwJymbdbokpS7pvCeLIxFmLBi3+GU6AJrw-uwIigYhlyCoYQW6G8R0afSUQrwIYspW8FjWYQ06xxQznIlxWJyT6183XWt0RfuaivoSlBRDBWcHSdF03WiIsxEkwQClzbUIf1clqO1kopKwM9d0va9byFTJukJkojTPVduomzcvESTw10EQ3JZNsTNu25r9SkAbUqYAZmWMJFKEtwRh4wZgFVhPJ2IMqRjO0iG9D0CIgA)

I am able to fix this if I change the `MakeKeyRequired` type utility to explicitly filter out undefined from the resulting value like this:

```
type MakeKeyRequired<Obj extends object, K extends keyof Obj> = Omit<Obj, K> & {
  [key in K]-?: Exclude<Obj[K], undefined>;
}
```

(`Exclude<..., undefined>` is added to the utility) - then it works inside the function as expected as well, but in my mind this shouldn't be necessary, as evidenced by the fact that TS is actually able to derive the correct type after all (see the last line on playground).

Can you TS experts help me out here?

Comment: The answer here is going to be that the compiler can't do much higher-order reasoning about types that depend on unresolved generic type parameters. It eagerly simplifies `Required<T>[K]` to `T[K]` instead of (say) `Exclude<T[K], undefined>`, as the former is probably almost always close enough to the truth.  By the way, you can use `type Oops<T extends { a?: { b: any } }> = Required<T>["a"]["b"];` as your [mre] here instead of all that other code if you care to.  You should probably include something like this in the plain text of your question instead of requiring people to click links.

Comment: I'm currently looking in github for any existing issue report of the form `type Oops<T extends { a?: { b: any } }> = Required<T>["a"]["b"];` but I can't find one.  I can imagine opening one, and fully expecting the response "it's not worth it to change this" and having it labeled a design limitation.  But until such time as that happens, I don't have an official answer to this question.

Comment: Eh, I'll file an issue about it and link back here.

Comment: All right, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46879... will check back later

Comment: Thank you very much jcalz (I'm a big fan), I don't have the self confidence to call something possibly bug / design limitation, but your example simplifies the issue very well. Maybe we can get a response and put this to rest.

Comment: Ah, this is working as intended... see [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wX2qVm) where you can call `genericFunction<{one: undefined}>()` and `genericFunction<{}>`, both of which *definitely* have `undefined` as the type of `T['one']` no matter how `Required` it is.  I can write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point #1: `Required<T>` does not  remove `undefined` from non-optional properties:**

Even though the `-?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) transforms [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) into required properties where `undefined` is excluded, it does not do anything to properties which start off as required.  Let's use [the `Required<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) to demonstrate:

```
type XNotUndefined = Required<{ x?: string | undefined }>
// type XNotUndefined = { x: string; } 

type XMaybeUndefined = Required<{ x: string | undefined }>
// type XMaybeUndefined =  { x: string | undefined; }
```

The type `XMaybeUndefined` has an `x` property which may be `undefined`.  So we can't assume that the `-?` modifier will necessarily result in a type with all defined properties.

This is working as intended and not a bug.

---

**Point #2: Types with possibly missing or `undefined` properties are assignable to those with optional properties:**

Additionally, the rules of [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out) in TypeScript for optional properties are *interesting*.  Let's look at a type with an optional property:

```
interface OptionalX {
  x?: string;
}
function acceptOptionalX(x: OptionalX) { }
```

Now let's remove the optional modifier on `x` without removing `undefined`:

```
interface RequiredX {
  x: string | undefined;
}
declare const r: RequiredX;
```

So a value of type `RequiredX` *definitely* has an `x` property, whose value is either a `string` or `undefined`.  It may be surprising to some to learn that `RequiredX extends OptionalX`:

```
acceptOptionalX(r); // okay, because RequiredX extends OptionalX;
```

And let's remove the `x` property entirely:

```
interface MissingX { }
declare const m: MissingX;
```

So a value of type `MissingX` may not have an `x` property at all.  It may also be surprising to some to learn that `MissingX extends OptionalX` as well:

```
acceptOptionalX(m); // okay, because MissingX extends OptionalX;
```

That means if you have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function with a type parameter `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `OptionalX`, like this:

```
function foo<T extends OptionalX>() { }
```

then it is acceptable to specify `T` with a type where the `x` property is either required but possibly `undefined`:

```
foo<RequiredX>(); // okay
```

and it is also acceptable to specify `T` with a type where the `x` property is not known to exist, and therefore is still possibly `undefined`:

```
foo<MissingX>(); // okay
```

This is working as intended and not a bug.

---

**Point #1 and Point #2 combine to produce the behavior you are seeing**

If we combine those together, we get this:

```
declare function bar<T extends OptionalX>(): Required<T>["x"];
const opt = bar<OptionalX>() // string
const req = bar<RequiredX>() // string | undefined
const mis = bar<MissingX>() // unknown
```

The type `Required<T>["x"]` where `T extends OptionalX` *cannot* be known to exclude `undefined`, and it *cannot* be known to extend `string`.  While `opt` is of type `string`, the value `req` is of type `string | undefined`, and the value `mis` is of type `unknown`.  So you cannot do anything much with `Required<T>["x"]`  without some extra processing like this:

```
declare function baz<T extends OptionalX>(): (Required<T>["x"] & string);
const opt2 = baz<OptionalX>() // string
const req2 = baz<RequiredX>() // string 
const mis2 = baz<MissingX>() // string
```

So the behavior you're seeing is intentional, and not a bug.

---

For the particular example in your code, you can see the issue like this:

```
genericFunction<{one: undefined}>() // returns undefined
genericFunction<{}>() // returns unknown
```

Note that you can't write `ReturnType<typeof genericFunction>` and get something fully accurate, because without support for higher kinded types (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) or arbitrary generic values (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574)), the compiler will just resolve the generic type parameter with its constraint.  So `ReturnType<typeof genericFunction>` only reflects what happens when you specify `NestedObj` as the type parameter:

```
type CalculatedType = ReturnType<typeof genericFunction>; // {deep: number}
genericFunction<NestedObj>() // {deep: number}
```

But it's definitely possible to get something out where `deep` is not a known property.

---

And there you go, it's expected behavior. Well, it wasn't quite expected by *me* before I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#46879](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46879), but now that @RyanCavanaugh (dev lead for the TS team at Microsoft) has [shown me the light](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46879#issuecomment-975716916) I expect it too.

It's definitely a bit strange, especially with missing properties, since [unsoundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) creeps in.  Generally if `X extends Y` and if `K extends keyof Y`, then `X[K] extends Y[K]` should be true.  But for missing/optional properties that's not true: `{} extends {x?: string}` and `"x" extends keyof {x?: string}`, but `unknown` does not extend `string | undefined`.  Oops.  I think the compiler will allow `Exclude<T["x"], undefined>` to be assignable to `string`, even though it could end up being `unknown`.  Unsoundness can be useful but it's hard to reason about.

So in your generic function you can do this:

```
type Fixed = Exclude<SrcWithRequiredOne["one"], undefined>["deep"]; // okay
```

And the compiler is happy with it, but be careful since weird things could still pop out:

```
function genericFunction2<T extends NestedObj>() {
  return null as unknown as Exclude<Required<T>["one"], undefined>["deep"];
}
genericFunction2<NestedObj>() // number, okay
genericFunction2<{ one: undefined }>() // never !!
genericFunction2<{}>() // unknown !!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgcge2AVQHYBMIDMCWqLpQC8UAShAI4CuOATgQDwDeUAHgPwBcUAzsLXgDmUAD5QqGbHgJQAvgD4AUAHplUUJFiIUk3PkIkWrbnwGpBAbjlRFijdBgBZAIYgARhDSY9MkuWp0jEYm-EKi4rrShAoqavawLu6ekfrEUFDBvKHm4RLeUVayNrZ4wBC0WM4AxtAA8mDAOAiozgA2MBmK6RwhZpaKsopYElWNzVDVNQ31Yy3tABTGUDNNczAAlBlyJahlFdXQ-jT06B1MXWy9YWJ5UvoWA4qYVa3O9FBVzXxQtNxHgacHpMINMGqs2jB5rR1lZVFAEABrVwAGigHiqzioPEOlGOBA6EFYZQwPGWYOaEIeilK5UqNSgjhwPB4QjOtkGz1e70+qG+AFtuIzmaygVUpsAVhSFnyYVA4YiUWiIBisdAhSzzASiRASWTZpTbEMRrMoFgEAgGAAVKCE4noUmStbyeabc6PM0W-4nGDO2XypEgIbmhjq1m+2FqBWB2yct7QYaoUarNFvK027W6x0Q31-XEAq3yADaACJWMWALoPHnfBANNJuVNZ9q+uVqUxCRTV4A-Sj11Ne-EtuHtnI3FIETtfbt8pl92ghpkawQ+l2tiII1AIADuqENsfeCaT4wbAC807adfa9eDmy7uPMB+gCyWy+WoAAyLJ9GGT3nd2vAAATH2Z5NiumzDtkgi-t89AUMBJCngwj7gWuI7CDB05MghKZnqGmpDm2UHFIaqhUI0rQ8JwdjgGqzgIhAADSEAgI+DC1G4ABW6Z2qSCBccqwCooxPGXqSDEgAgWDLFx8hpLUM7AOxXHCXJn7nOkhYSVAeBQIx5YALRcDJnGFvpDyDLEBnWTZtl2fZNmxDwCBULQ9L8ZxgnqLRNGaAACggwpuK0TEsaSJDFs0EDFuExbAFuCDFg88RwBAfAEBx3GGFAhYATezEgDpqBQAFQUhQVPDlsZLCYCC3CoFQfIeLQ1iyFSRqJiagg6uUOBVAAYsaqznhmV6pel6CZS2GneZoADKbkAOo4MAAAWj61PgaQuAxBVsZaqKRfgxbyA86TxP1OCsL4UAAKKsC8VCYAwC1VMta0bfgJZRRWqK3D46BFsWtVgBWEbwgGtjpPQwCucVDWtK0EykhIG7bsVzikq973rXmJybRA33HZWjy2N1+ACANQ3NMw8L4Nw-1RHIhEQ64UDzFuK2rS53bWYS1QSuScx+bQtblKAlq0aSzioCAW6uOsijk71VOdcNTAKKu-ps-MultEjGLYjwiu+dAADCbRVFQrxlOgkuaH4ECw7QqD2xADD2FJUDK5Tg1q80p1Kz1vvU6gDDjbbU1a2oTAg-VjXNZZHVHsVPt9X7KeASNvFQBHGWyauM0w3DUAI0jmPrpuO7I3dD2tE97v7UDP3ln946AyWINg6Taeq5ntNRQz7fM9HpcQAAbuUQcU+nodZxrLOo1Xu69xnsxZ3nk0FxBagNU1U9AA)